# VM crashed during ubuntu update and doesn't start anymore

Tags: boot, 20.04, updates, crash

I was trying to update my VM from ubuntu 20.04 to 22 via command line and it froze after aprox 20 mins. I restarted it and now it doesn't boot anymore and it gives me the message: A problem has occurred and the system can't recover. Please contact a system administrator.

Any thoughts? I briefly see an error with Failed to start Dispatcher daemon for systemd-networkd.